# Relationships in Django

Tags: django-models, django-views

I have following model class set up:

```
class Moc(models.Model):
    .....my other fields.....

    def __str__(self):
        return self.moc_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('moc_content_update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Verifier(models.Model):
    moc = models.ForeignKey(Moc, related_name='verifiers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
    verifier_group = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True, null=True)    
    verifier_name = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)    
    verify_due = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created = not self.pk
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created:
            VerifierSignOff.objects.create(verifier=self)


class VerifierSignOff(models.Model):
    verifier = models.OneToOneField(Verifier, related_name='verifiersignoff', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approve = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
    reject = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    signoff_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=256, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

My views are stetted up to create Moc instance, add Verifiers (in total 3 users) with respective VerifierSignOff and display it on my template without any issue.

My views.py:

```
def verify_coordinate_view(request, pk):

    moc = get_object_or_404(Moc, pk=pk)

    # I guess I need to have MOC Status logic here

    return render(request, 'moc/moc_content_verification.html', context={'pk':pk, 'moc':moc, })


def verifier_signoff_view(request, pk):
    
    verifiersignoff = VerifierSignOff.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = VerifierSignForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VerifierSignForm(request.POST, instance=verifiersignoff)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            if verifiersignoff.approve is True and verifiersignoff.reject is True:
                return HttpResponseForbidden('You have either APPROVE or REJECT - operation not allowed!')
            else:
                form.save()
        return redirect('verify_coordinate', pk=verifiersignoff.verifier.moc_id)
        # return redirect('index')
    else:
        return render(request, 'moc/verify_signoff.html', context={'verifiersignoff': verifiersignoff, 'form': form})
```

I am displaying everything on my template i.e. I can add/remove my users, approve/reject the record, etc.

**My aim is to display my Moc instance status i.e. VERIFIED (if 3oo3 Users approve the record) or REJECTED (if anyone from 3oo3 will reject record in other words if some user rejects record becomes not valid anymore despite if other 2 users already have had it approved).**

I am rendering this process on my template using of for loop:

my pseudo template:

```
{% for obj in moc.verifiers.all %}

<tr style="text-align: center>
   <td>---my sign-off / delete user---buttons</td>
   <td>{{ forloop.counter }}{{ obj.verifier_group }}</td>
   <td>{{ obj.verifier_name }}</td>
   <td>{{ obj.verify_due|date:'d M Y' }}</td>
   <td>
     <input class="form-check-input-bg" type="checkbox" value="{{ obj.verifiersignoff.approve }}" checked onclick="return false">
   </td>                                                                                                             
   <td>
     <input class="form-check-input-bg" type="checkbox" value="{{ obj.verifiersignoff.reject }}" onclick="return false">
   </td>                                                                                                                           
   <td>{{ obj.verifiersignoff.signoff_date|date:'d M Y'}}</td>                                        
   <td>{{ obj.verifiersignoff.verified_by }}</td>
   <td>{{ obj.note }}</td>
  {% empty %}
   <td colspan="8" style="WIDTH: 130px">No verifiers assigned yet...</td>

</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

I am able to display individual for loop object approve/reject status individually in my template, however I want to display consolidated STATUS as per my above description i.e. something like:

```
MOC STATUS: {{?????? I don't know how I can generate this variable in my logic ?????}}
```

My template snippet:
[image]

Comment: anybody could help here?

Comment: Yes, I will definitely try but sometime later.

Comment: @SunderamDubey, Thank you for your feedback and looking forward your support!

Comment: Can you share entire template (I mean entire table html) and `Moc` model (I mean all fields)?

Comment: You haven't replied yet here.

Comment: @SunderamDubey, Sorry I could not share it (for some other reasons) and even don't see value as what I want to achieve is that I am looking to consolidate my VerifierSignOff instances against individual User as per described logic. I do not want to store anything extra in my db. just want to consolidate 3 separate approve=True as one world - VERIFIED. i.e. something annotate/aggregate like...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248669/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-ss-ss).